# How do I network my autoresponder with Paypal for recurring subscription payments?

Tags: paypal-subscriptions

I am wanting to create a fixed term membership site (12 months) that drip feeds information each month to paid members via an autoresponder. I am wanting to use Paypal as the payment gateway. Does anyone know how I trigger the delivery of the first month's content once payment is received and cancel delivery when they cancel?

I know how to set up the autoresponder and I know how to setup a subscription in Paypal. I am just not sure how to get the two to communicate.

Comment: Can you elaborate this some more? What kind of platform are you using (besides paypal), which programming languages are involved?

Answer (score 0):

You put the URL you want PayPal to call in your PayPal profile and every time something happens such as a payment or subscription cancellation the PayPal system will send a HTTP request to your URL.

Your job is to parse out the information sends in the request and take action accordingly. They send a lot of information with things like subscriptionid, payment amount etc. etc.